# Displaying menus under Wordpress twentysixteen theme

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a Wordpress installation-in-progress at http://dev.cjshayward.com. I have done a few things to get a main menu to display under a lightly edited child theme to the twentysixteen theme, but so far there is no menu displaying at the top.

What do I need to get a menubar with a few top-level menus to appear?

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: @SamuelAsor, did you mean besides the link to http://dev.cjshayward.com ?

Comment: Exactly. It would go a long way.

Comment: It would be better to show the **few things** you have done to get a main menu to display...for better understanding of your question.